# AttributeError: 'BaseQuerySet' object has no attribute 'is_authenticated'

Tags: mongoengine, flask-login, flask-mongoengine

I'm using flask-login and MongoDB as my database to store user profiles.

When checking whether a user is authenticated in my login function:

```
@bp.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('routes.index'))
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'BaseQuerySet' object has no attribute 'is_authenticated'
```

My User object is extending UserMixin from flask-login.

Any idea what might me wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK i found it - in my user_loader function i did something like that:

```
@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.objects(_id=ObjectId(id))
```

whereas the correct way to get a single result (not entire collection) using mongoengine (which apparently translates _id into id), would be this:

```
@login.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.objects(id=ObjectId(id)).first()
```

Comment: You don't need to convert the id to an ObjectId using ObjectId(id)....
and you also can use the .get(id=the_id) instead of User.objects(id=the_id):

@login.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
      try:
            return User.objects.get(id=user_id)
      except Exception as e:
            print(e)

Answer (score 1):

As you said in your answer, the interface to `MongoEngine` requires `id` instead of `_id` in the queries. However if you check the object representation, the ID of a Document is still stored in the `._id` variable.

Also you don't need to convert the_id to an ObjectId() using ObjectId(the_id), and you also can use the User.objects.get(id=the_id) function to get a single Document instead of User.objects(id=the_id).first() as in:

```
@login.user_loader  
def load_user(user_id): 
    try: 
        return User.objects.get(id=user_id) 
    except Exception as e: 
        print(e)
        raise
```